# Using pistachio paste instead of an extract - what proportion of paste should I use?

Tags: flavor, extracts

While I have a specific baking goal in mind, if there are answers that apply generally to all cooking/baking that'd be great.

I have a biscotti recipe that I often adapt with different mix-ins and different flavor extracts. But I want to make a pistachio version now and want a strong pistachio flavor flavor.

Can pistachio paste be substituted 1:1 for an extract? I'd guess the paste is going to be weaker in flavor than an extract, so am I looking at a 2:1 or even greater substitution?

Comment: What do you mean by "pistachio paste"? Pure ground pistachios, or a synthetic product meant for flavoring dishes?

Comment: Good point @rumtscho.  I assumed pure ground pistachios as that's what I've heard of and what dominates hits online (recipes to make it).

Comment: Thanks for the question! I meant a paste made from pistachios. I wasn't aware there were synthetic pistachio products. The paste I've ordered is "100% pure California pistachios".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used pistachio paste, and it's a while since I've used extract, but I'm pretty certain that the amount of paste you'd need would be enough to change the texture of your biscotti.

To my mind, a "strong pistachio flavour" means almost as strong as pistachios themselves, meaning that you'd need 10s of percent of paste in your dough, instead of less than about 1% extract.

Comment: I have a thought, though I'm not sure if it would work.  I've included roughly shopped pistachios in biscotti before, but I wonder about a layer of pistachio paste folded in (perhaps slightly sweetened paste). as the marzipan is in stollen.  I'm not sure what would happen at the 2nd bake though - it might get a bit too toasted on the surfaces